# Facebook Login SDK for Android provides no email

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am building an application which requires my users to login via facebook.
For some user accounts the problem arises that `email` field is `null` after they successfully allow all the permissions. **This only happens to some users**. It is quite possible that the user does not has an `email` at all in the facebook databases and has signed up using a mobile number. What to do in this case?

Also one of the user reported that he uses an `email` address to login to his facebook account but the same user when signs in using facebook in my app, the `email` field is `null`.